# Understanding Persistence.xml in JPA

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, persistence.xml

I am trying to understand the following things:

When I make an EJB project and deploys it to Glassfish do I set up JDBC resources/connection pools at the administrator center of Glassfish or do I add all the different properites for username, password etc in the persistence.xml? I don't understand one bit of that.

I do not understand why we have both JDBC resource and JDBC Connection pool either. What is it and what is the difference between them? Could somebody explain me these things or/and provide some good link about the persistence.xml file and the part around it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to define a JDBC resource rather than putting the information in the persistence.xml. In this way you are going to take advantage of connection pooling. You are going to define the JNDI name you provided for the JDBC resource in the persistence.xml.

> What is it and what is the difference between them

Below I pasted some parts of the Glassfish 3.x help. Check it out. It's really helpful

**JDBC connection pool**

A JDBC connection pool contains a group of JDBC connections that are created when the connection pool is registered

**JDBC resource**

A Java DataBase Connectivity (JDBC) resource (data source) provides applications with the means of connecting to a database. Typically, the administrator creates a JDBC resource for each database accessed by the applications deployed in a domain; however, more than one JDBC resource can be created for a database.

Applications get a database connection from a connection pool by looking up a data source on the Java Naming and Directory Interface (JNDI) API tree and then requesting a connection. The connection pool associated with the data source provides the connection to the application.

Think of the data source(JDBC) resource as a factory for a facade of some type of data service(Connection Pool). In this case it implicitly gets a connection from the pool and provides it to your application.

An example persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="WebApplication2PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This line is the JNDI name I gave to my JDBC resourse:

```
 <jta-data-source>jdbc/sample</jta-data-source>
```

You dont need to define anything related to the database connection in your persistence.xml this way...just the JNDI name of the resource

Comment: Thank you! A bit clearer now. So the connection property details is actually the same in both places? But it is more convenient to bring these details away from the code? (If you have time I am in the Java chat channel)

Comment: Since you are going to deploy your app in Glassfish you want your connections to be provided by a datasource(JDBC Resource) configured in Glassfish and not to open connection directly from your application.You could define a <persistence-unit name="ShopPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"> but you want you connections provided by Glassfish since Glassfish is going to automatically manage your transactions too. With an application server you have your transactions automatically managed so you use the jta-data-source.

Comment: You save your self from transaction management code and a lot of configurations properties(database credentials, url etc) in the persistence.xml which in the end you set in your connection pooling configuration.

Answer (score 0):

When you configure a data source in your application server, all you need to set in `persistence.xml` is the JNDI name of that data source.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please elaborate your answer more? What is the difference between setting all the properties in the file and just adding the the JNDI name. I have many questions un-answered.

Comment: well, the difference is that the app server creates and manages it.

Comment: But the "configuration" is the same in both places? It is just to move the details of it out the application? (available in chat-Java room)

Comment: Yes. And to make it easier for OPs to (re)configure it later in production

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the book that I read to learn Spring and Hibernate. The book name is *Professional Java for Web Applications* written by *Nicholas S. Williams*. I think this will be helpful for many people.

> Creating the Persistence Configuration:
>
> To use the entities you create, you must define a persistence unit. Doing so is simple. Create a
>   persistence.xml file not dissimilar from a deployment descriptor, but with far fewer options
>   to worry about. The root element of a persistence configuration file is `<persistence>`. This
>   element may contain one or more `<persistence-unit>` elements. No other elements are
>   within `<persistence>`. `<persistence-unit>` has two attributes: name specifies the name of
>   the persistence unit and transaction-type indicates whether this persistence unit uses Java
>   Transaction API (JTA) transactions or standard local transactions.
>   You must specify a name, which is how you locate the persistence unit in code. If not specified,
>   transaction-type defaults to JTA in a Java EE application server and RESOURCE_LOCAL in a Java
>   SE environment or simple Servlet container. However, to prevent unexpected behavior it’s best to
>   always set this value explicitly instead of relying on a default value.
>   `<persistence-unit>` contains the following inner elements. None of them are required (so
>   `<persistence-unit>` may be empty); however, you must specify whichever elements you use in the
>   following order:
>
> - `<description>` contains a useful description for this persistence unit. Although it makes
>     reading the persistence file easier, it has no semantic value.
> - `<provider>` specifies the fully qualified class name of the javax.persistence.spi
>     .PersistenceProvider implementation used for this persistence unit. By default, when you
>     look up the persistence unit, the API will use the first JPA provider on the classpath. You
>     can include this element to mandate a specific JPA provider.
> - You can use either `<jta-data-source>` or `<non-jta-data-source>` (but not both) to
>     use a JNDI DataSource resource. You may use `<jta-data-source>` only if
>     transaction-type is JTA; likewise you may use `<non-jta-data-source>` only
>     if transaction-type is RESOURCE_LOCAL. Specifying a DataSource causes the persistence
>     unit to use that DataSource for all entity operations.
> - `<mapping-file>` specifies the classpath-relative path to an XML mapping file. If you don’t
>     specify any `<mapping-file>`, the provider looks for orm.xml. You may specify multiple
>     `<mapping-file>` elements to use multiple mapping files.
> - You can use one or more `<jar-file>` elements to specify a JAR file or JAR files that the
>     JPA provider should scan for mapping-annotated entities. Any @Entity, @Embeddable,
>     @javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass, or @javax.persistence.Converter classes
>     found are added to the persistence unit.
> - You can use one or more `<class>` elements to indicate specific @Entity, @Embeddable,
>     @MappedSuperclass, or @Converter classes that should be added to the persistence unit.
>     You must annotate the class or classes with JPA annotations.
> - Using `<exclude-unlisted-classes />` or `<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>` indicates that the provider should ignore classes not
>     specified with `<jar-file>` or `<class>`. Omitting `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` or using
>     `<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>` causes the JPA
>     provider to scan the classpath location of the persistence file for JPA-annotated classes. If
>     persistence.xml is located in a JAR file, that JAR file (and only that JAR file) is scanned
>     for classes. If persistence.xml is located in a directory-based classpath location (such as /
>     WEB-INF/classes), that directory (and only that directory) is scanned for classes. Prior to
>     Hibernate 4.3.0 and Spring Framework 3.2.5, specifying this element with the value false
>     was incorrectly interpreted as true.
> - `<shared-cache-mode>` indicates how entities are cached in the persistence unit (if the JPA
>     provider supports caching, which is optional). NONE disables caching, whereas ALL enables
>     caching for all entities. ENABLE_SELECTIVE means that only entities annotated @javax
>     .persistence.Cacheable or @Cacheable(true) (or marked as cacheable in orm.xml)
>     are cached. DISABLE_SELECTIVE results in caching of all entities except those annotated
>     @Cacheable(false) (or marked as non-cacheable in orm.xml). The default value,
>     UNSPECIFIED, means that the JPA provider decides what the effective default is. Hibernate
>     ORM defaults to ENABLE_SELECTIVE, but relying on this is not portable.
> - `<validation-mode>` indicates if and how Bean Validation should be applied to entities.
>     NONE means that Bean Validation is not enabled, whereas CALLBACK makes the provider
>     validate all entities on insert, update, and delete. AUTO has an effective value of CALLBACK
>     if a Bean Validation provider exists on the classpath and an effective value of NONE if no
>     Bean Validation provider exists on the classpath. If you enable validation, the JPA provider
>     configures a new Validator to validate your entities. If you have configured a special
>     Spring Framework Validator with your custom localized error codes, the JPA provider
>     ignores it. As such, it’s best to set the validation mode to NONE and use Bean Validation
>     before your persistence layer is invoked.
> - `<properties>` provides a way to specify other JPA properties, including standard JPA
>     properties (such as JDBC connection string, username, and password, or schema generation
>     settings) as well as provider-specific properties (such as Hibernate settings). You specify
>     one or more properties using nested  elements, each with a name and value
>     attribute.

*`Nicholas S. Williams, Professional Java for Web Applications, (Indianapolis, Indiana: John Wiley & Sons, Inc., 2014), pg 584-585`*