# Some confusion surrounding JDBC Resources and JDBC Connection pools Glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish

I am about to make a connection to my database and I am using EJB and JPA. I have recently started doing these technologies so I have some problems understand it all at this point:)
I know that the persistence.xml is needed in order to use JPA. It is the file where I configure how to connect to the database, that I know. However it seems like there are multiple ways of doing it.

What would be the difference (or when should I even use the one alternative over the other?) of defining properties such as username, database, password etc. in the persistence.xml file and in Glassfish? Advantages/disadvantages if any.

Underneath on the image I posted I have JDBC Resources and JDBC Connection Pools. I am a litte confused about the terminology of the two. Why don't we add properties such as username, database, password and so on in the JDBC Resources? Could someone explain the difference between them and what they mean?

> JDBC Resources
>
> A JDBC resource (data source) provides applications with a means of
>   connecting to a database. Typically, the administrator creates a JDBC
>   resource for each database accessed by the applications deployed in a
>   domain. (However, more than one JDBC resource can be created for a
>   database.)
>   http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19316-01/820-4335/ablih/index.html

I think it strange that we add such properties on the pool but not in the resource, but I probably misunderstand the concepts.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the "JDBC connection pools" you can create container managed JDBC data sources (with connection pooling capabilities). The data source needs to know about at least the JDBC driver, the JDBC URL, username and password.

In the "JDBC resources" you can bind those container managed JDBC data sources to one or more JNDI names so that they are by JNDI available to the deployed web application.

In the `persistence.xml` you can specify whether to use a local data source or to use a container managed data source. If you want to use a container managed data source, then you should specify its JNDI name. Using a container managed data source has the advantage that you can share a single data source among multiple web applications. In case of JPA, it has also the advantage that you can make use of JTA (container managed transactions) so that you don't need to call `transaction.begin()`, `commit()`, `rollback()` etc in every method.

Comment: So when do you set properties in the persistence.xml? When you have a application in Java SE? But otherwise it essentially the same properties and so on you can define in the persistence.xml?

Comment: Yes, only in a plain vanilla Java SE application it makes sense (for example, when you'd like to unit-test your JPA project). In a Java EE container you'd really like to go for JTA with a container managed datasource so that your EJBs can do their job nicely in transactional context. Usually you provide another `persistence.xml` in your web project which inherits the classes from the JPA project and overrides the transaction type to be JTA, along with a `<jta-data-source>` pointing to the JNDI name of the container managed data source.

Comment: Okey, then I think I start to understand it:)

Comment: I am reading Enterprise JavaBeans 3.1 and I haven't gotten to JNDI and JTA yet so it is a bit hard to understand those parts, but I am getting there!