# what does Context,DataSource depict?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jdbc, datasource

There are certain things that i don't understand when i am writing a program to query into the database.

In the following 2 lines of code :

```
Context context = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatasource");
```

What does the first instruction do ? What is context and what is `initial context` ? I have read the doc but don't understand it.

Then what is a `DataSource` ?

While working with netbeans I have to make a new file of category `JDBCConnectionPool` :

[image]

What is a `JDBC Connection Pool` and what is a `JDBC Resource` ?

---

And what does `Steady Pool Size` and `Max Pool Size` mean ? What is a pool size ?
[image]

Comment: Too many questions in one post.  If this is all incomprehensible to you, then you probably shouldn't be trying to do this until you have mastered the underlying concepts.

Answer (score 2):

```
What is context and what is initial context ?
```

`Context`: represents a naming context, which consists of a set of name-to-object bindings. It contains methods for examining and updating these bindings. [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/javax/naming/Context.html)

`InitialContext`: Is a class, or you can say the starting context for performing naming operations, and this class is implementing the `Context` interface and provide the implementation.
[mustRead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/basics/prepare/initial.html)

```
DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatasource");

what is a DataSource:
```

The above line of code is showing that,You are retrieving a DataSource object by looking up a JNDI location.

```
JDBCConnectionPool
```

JDBCConnection Pooling is conceptually same as any other form of object pooling such as `String` object pooling. Database connection creation are always expensive because of the overhead of establishing a network connection and initializing a database connection session in the back end database [source](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200601/JDBCConnectionPooling.html)

```
JDBC Resource:
```

[read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772678/some-confusion-surrounding-jdbc-resources-and-jdbc-connection-pools-glassfish)

Very good example of steady pooling [readHere](https://bigip-blogs-cms-adc.oracle.com/technical/entry/jdbc_pool_manager_steady_pool)