# developing a webservice using java and mysql

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services

I am not familiar with websrvices and mysql ..i followed this http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html tutorial and developed a RESTful web service in Java with the JAX-RS reference implementation Jersey.

I want to create an websrevice using eclipse which select the data from mysql database and display the result in xml format.

I got lots of sample developing webservices with PHP and mysql but i want to develop in java.

Please suggest me some good tutorial/links on this or idea which may help me. i want to use that webservice in my android application.

In the above example ,i am not getting where to put the connection string to establish the connection between MySQL database and java files.

Here is the TodoResource.java :

```
package de.vogella.jersey.jaxb;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import de.vogella.jersey.jaxb.model.Todo;

@Path("/todo")
public class TodoResource {
    // This method is called if XMLis request


    @GET
    @Produces( { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    //@Produces( { MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public Todo getXML() {
        Todo todo = new Todo();


        todo.setSummary("This is my first todo");
        todo.setDescription("This is my first todo");
        todo.setMy_id(1);
        return todo;



    }

    // This can be used to test the integration with the browser
    @GET
    @Produces( { MediaType.TEXT_XML })
    public Todo getHTML() {
        Todo todo = new Todo();
        todo.setSummary("This is my first todo");
        todo.setDescription("This is my first todo");
        return todo;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start here : http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/21-restlet.html

You can create a  java class/method that encapsulates the Business logic,  for example a method like  getData(DataFormat xml/html, whatData)  which connects to the mysql database and retrieves records and then transforms it into required format, call this method within  getXML() and getHTML()

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC makes REST based development very easy. Refer to this [blog](http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/)

Answer (score 0):

The example you linked to does not actually make use of a database but uses in-memory *Todo*'s to provide the data. In section 8 the author states

> Create the following data model and a Singleton which serves as the
>   data provider for the model. We use the implementation based on an
>   enumeration.

The data model is the *Todo* class.

The data provider is the *TodoDao* enum. The purpose of *TodoDao*, is essentially to store *Todo*'s in memory. In other words, it performs the function that would otherwise be done by a database.

What therefore needs to be done, is to:

1. Replace *TodoDao* with a database.
2. Map *Todo* to a table in the database.

   - To connect Java objects to a database, you can use an Object Relational Mapper (ORM), which can be achieved by using the Java Persistence API (JPA).
   - Therefore, to map *Todo* to a database table, it needs to be annotated with JPA annotations, thus creating a JPA Entity.

Have a look the accepted answer to [REST/JSON Web Services Java EE Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3891380/3578158), it should shed some light on what needs to be done. Part 1 covers creating a database, while Part 2 covers creating and annotating JPA entities (Part 3 - JAXB Bindings for xml or json, Part 4 - The RESTFul Service, Part 5 - The Client).

If difficulties are still encountered, have a look at the answer I posted for [Need to write a RESTful JSON service in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622521/need-to-write-a-restful-json-service-in-java/24047656#24047656), that should be suitable for someone who wants more nitty-gritty to, as a starting point, connect to a single table in a database and create a RESTful Web Service with JSON/XML representations using the following.

- IDE: Eclipse IDE for Jave EE Developers (Kepler), comes with Maven built in
- Database: MySQL (also makes use of MySQL Workbench)
- Application Server: GlassFish 4.0
- Java EE 7 (JAX-RS, JPA, JAXB, etc)
- Any REST Client for testing: (eg Postman)