# Is it possible to create java restful web service based on joins on multiple tables?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am trying to create a set of restful webservice in java using netbeans and mysql database. Netbeans allows creation of webservice on top of tables and views. I want to create a webservice based on joins on multiple tables along with where clause with conditions based on web service parameters.

My questions are:

1. is this possible?
2. what are different alternatives and the best possible way to achieve this?
3. are there any samples available?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.
And since this is already answered in detail, i will give you link for same.

[Need to write a RESTful JSON service in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622521/need-to-write-a-restful-json-service-in-java/24047656#24047656)

Comment: If one adds a comment on the reason to down-vote the answer, it would help avoiding mistakes

Comment: Thanks Maulik, your links talks about single table but not web service based on join multiple tables. Can you point me to the sample with multiple tables?

Comment: [This link](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm) will help you to create web service via Net Beans on multiple tables. It uses a different database though

Comment: Hi Maulik, the post here talks about two tables but not about the join of two tables...